# Reading Time column in R

Tags: r

I am reading a Excel file with time as a column.

This column has values like

```
23:29:04
23:04:31
21:55:37
21:52:27
21:49:53
```

When I read this column using R , read column comes as a numeric value :

```
0.961469907
0.913622685
0.911423611
0.907094907 
0.906250000 
0.899490741
```

There is no correspondence between above mentioned Excel and R column values. These are just samples.

**I tried using**

```
strptime(TimeStamp,format="%H:%M:%S)
```

It gives all values as `NA`.

Please suggest how to read time correctly in R.

Answer (score 3):

These numbers are fractions of a day corresponding to times. Time objects are, e.g., implemented in package chron:

```
library(chron)
x <- c(0.961469907, 0.913622685, 0.911423611, 0.907094907, 0.906250000, 0.899490741)
x <- times(x)
print(x)
#[1] 23:04:31 21:55:37 21:52:27 21:46:13 21:45:00 21:35:16
```

Comment: Or package `hms`.

Answer (score -1):

Read the columns as string and wrap your strptime command with as.POSIXct:

```
as.POSIXct(strptime(TimeStamp,format="%H:%M:%S"))
```

Comment: Time in R must have a valid date associated with it.  Another option is the to  use the chron package as recommended below.

Comment: If the excel file is saved as .csv and imported to R using `read.csv` command with `stringsAsFactors = F` argument, it will be imported as strings.